# Settings Bundle and SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

During objective C days, we would store the username and password in the settings bundle, so that if the user wanted to change either item, they could do so via the settings of the app in question.

While the username is unlikely to change (given that the iPhone is a personal device), there may be rare cases where this may occur in my app, and the password may be changed from the desktop version, where the user will have to update it here.

1. Is the settings bundle still the preferred way to handle this scenario in SwiftUI or is there a SwiftUI based alternative?
2. How do we handle the Settings Bundle with SwiftUI? Could someone post a code sample or a link to an appropriate article?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Storing sensitive data in Settings is not a good idea. Here is a good summary of your options: [Secret Management on iOS](https://nshipster.com/secrets/).

To access Settings (`NSUserDefaults`) from Swift see [How to save user settings using UserDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults)